# jQuery show text in a div after a "select" action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know the jQuery terminology for this: how do I get jQuery to work dynamically and refesh or reload the `.test` div when a new selection is made? I have to reload the whole page for the "case" text to appear in the `test` div.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g7601ckw/6/

**jQuery:**

```
var selectedsubject = $('.wpcf7-select').find(":selected").text();

switch (selectedsubject) {
    case ('I Love You'):
            $('.test').text('I Know You Do');
break;
    case ('I Hate You'):
            $('.test').text('You Don\'t');
break; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<label>Subject

<select name="your-subject" class="wpcf7-select">

<option value="">-Select a Subject-</option>

<option value="I Love You">I Love You</option>
<option value="I Hate You">I Hate You</option>

</select>
</label>

<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`.change` event](https://api.jquery.com/change/) of the `select` tag.

Here is an example, based on your code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.wpcf7-select').change(function() {
    var selectedsubject = $('.wpcf7-select').val();

    switch (selectedsubject) {
      case ('I Love You'):
        $('.test').text('I Know You Do');
        break;
      case ('I Hate You'):
        $('.test').text('You Don\'t');
        break; 
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Subject

<select name="your-subject" class="wpcf7-select">

<option value="">-Select a Subject-</option>

<option value="I Love You">I Love You</option>
<option value="I Hate You">I Hate You</option>

</select>
</label>

<div class="test"></div>
```

Also note that you don't need the `.find(':selected')` when you have a `select` tag, you can just use the `val()` function on that element (already changed in my code).

Comment: Thanks! This works great. I can see what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Really wierd issue when I try this on localhost or a live site: "SyntaxError: missing : after case label" for the first case. And I have all single quotes in the text strings escaped.